# How to apply css to only that particular icon that is hovered over when the icons are part of a loop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This makes all the **DeleteRoundedIcon** either visibile or invisible whenever the mouse hovers on any one of the **DeleteRoundedIcon** icons as they all are part of a loop.
I want to apply this styling only to the icon that is currently being hovered.
The icons are material-ui icons.
How to do so ???

```
const [iconOpacity, setIconOpacity] = useState(0);

<div className = "chat__body">
    {messages.map(function(message, index) {
        {
            return (
                <p>
                    <span className="chat__desc">{message.message}</span>
                    <span className="chat__timestamp">{message.timestamp}</span>
                    <IconButton
                        onMouseOver={() => setIconOpacity(1)} onMouseOut={() => setIconOpacity(0)}
                        onClick={() => deleteClicked(index)}
                        style={{padding: "0", opacity: iconOpacity}}>
                            <DeleteRoundedIcon fontSize="small"/>
                        </IconButton>
                </p>
            );
        }
    }}
</div>
```

Comment: Why not go with the css way of using `:hover` pseudo-class to handle the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule & note to self: whenever there is a simple CSS solution to a problem don't go after javascript to solve it. You can simply solve your problem with the use of `hover` pseudo-class; in that case, whenever you hover on any of the DeleteRoundedIcon only that icon would change appearance:

```
<div className = "chat__body">
{messages.map(function(message, index) {
    {
        return (
            <p>
                <span className="chat__desc">{message.message}</span>
                <span className="chat__timestamp">{message.timestamp}</span>
                <IconButton
                    onClick={() => deleteClicked(index)}
                    className="roundedIcon">
                        <DeleteRoundedIcon fontSize="small"/>
                    </IconButton>
            </p>
        );
    }
}}
```

and in your style file:

```
 .roundedIcon{  
    padding: "0";  
    opacity: 0;
}
.roundedIcon:hover{  
    opacity:1;
}
```